# How to design a performant friends of friends database table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

For a bit of context I'm currently working on a website called http://www.clubsofa.org where the concept is that people can do a friends of friends search on a google map with the intention of allowing them to make contact with second degree friends whilst travelling.
Currently the setup is PostgreSQL with a table called friends which stores two unique user ids (where a friendship is only stored once, e.g person a, person b states that a is friends with b and b is friends with a). When querying friends of friends I get all of the friends of the current user then search for all of their friends but this takes an extremely long time with few users on the AWS ec2 instance it's running on.
The other method I've tried is storing friend relations two ways and then indexing on the first column, however, this was slightly slower.
One of the ways I was thinking of setting it up was storing a persons friends in their user_details entry as a JSON object and then updating this lazily, but haven't got around to testing this yet.

Is there any good way to set this up?

Comment: If you are using Postgres, then store the friends in the SQLish way, as a friends table with a column for each friend.

Comment: I've currently got that and it's extremely slow. Is there not a more performant way to do it?

Comment: "*and it's extremely slow*" - Show us your current table definitions (as `create table` statements) the query you are using and read: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Answer (score 1):

You could more easily query the table in which you store the friendship in just "one direction" by placing a view on it of the form ...

```
create view all_friendships
as
select friend_from,
       friend_to
from   friendships
union all
select friend_to,
       friend_from
from   friendships;
```

With unique indexing on (friend_from,friend_to) and (friend_to,friend_from), this ought to be easy to maintain and easy to query.

So getting friends of friends would be:

```
select distinct
       f2.friend_to
from   all_friendships f1 join
       all_friendships f2 on (f2.friend_from = f1.friend_to)
where  f1.friend_from = 12345 and
       f2.friend_to != 12345;
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a really good idea I hadn't thought of doing that